# Resigning Apk with debug.keystore Android

Tags: android, cmd, robotium, signing

I am trying to resign existing apk with android debug keystore but I am unable to install the apk after signing it. It says application not installed.

Here are the only two lines of code which I used: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/51AaW.png

Comment: You say resigned has it been signed before?

Comment: yes. Its signed I just need to resign it for Robotium testing,

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while but I am under the impression you have to unsign the old keys before resigning with your new key.

You can do this either using: [recorder.robotium.com/downloads/re-sign.jar](http://recorder.robotium.com/downloads/re-sign.jar) which you can see how it is used [here](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles) or by removing the original signed files yourself via zip -d yourapp.apk "META-INF*" (or delete the META-INF folder yourself manually from within the apk file (you can use say 7-zip to do this)).

If it doesn't work please let me know and I can help you further and if it does then excellent!